# export org-file to pdf on the CLI

Tags: org-mode

I wonder if it is possible to write a bash oneline to export org-files to pdf. Something like this

```
emacs -q --eval 'org-latex-export-to-pdf manual.org'
```

I'm aware of the [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) project. I would like to do it with emacs, as I also want to add some style options for the export.

I have a document where I will occasionally work with others. To make it easy for them I would like to add a Makefile to generate the pdf.

**EDIT**

Solution from the comments

```
emacs --batch -q --eval '(progn (find-file "manual.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'
```

Comment: https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk

Comment: `emacs --batch -q --eval '(progn (find-file "manual.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'` should do the trick. (untested). AFAIK you need to use elisp syntax for eval.

Comment: What does `latex` have to do with this??

Comment: @Tobias I think your comment is an answer :)  Maybe use with-current-buffer instead of progn though.

Comment: @Qudit Maybe `with-current-buffer` makes the intention more clear. I agree whith this. Nevertheless, `find-file` makes the buffer corresponding to the argument current. So, `with-current-buffer` does not change the functionality in any way.

Comment: @Tobias The point of using with-current-buffer is that it restores the previous current buffer afterwards. This is useful if you have an active emacs session running in another window.

Comment: @Qudit Wouldn't that only matter if you run `emacsclient` instead of `emacs --batch -q ...`?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, for some reason I read it as emacsclient instead of emacs.